# Inequality about sum of complex numbers.

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Let ${\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n}$ be complex numbers, prove that

$$|\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\cdots+\alpha_n|^2 \leq n(|\alpha_1|^2+|\alpha_2|^2+\cdots+|\alpha_n|^2).$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $\alpha_1 +\alpha_2 + \ldots + \alpha_n = \alpha_1 \cdot 1 + \alpha_2 \cdot 1 + \ldots + \alpha_n \cdot 1$.

Answer (score 2):

This follows from Cauchy-Schwarz inequality by putting $x_i=\alpha_i$ and $y_i=1$ for $i=1,2,...,n$. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

Answer (score 1):

You have $|ab| \le \frac{1}{2} ( |a|^2 + |b|^2 )$ (since $(|a|-|b|)^2 \ge 0$).

Hence $|\alpha_1+\alpha_2+...+\alpha_n|^2 \leq \sum_i \sum_j |\alpha_i| |\alpha_j| \le \frac{1}{2} \sum_i \sum_j (|\alpha_i|^2 +  |\alpha_j|^2 ) = n \sum_i  |\alpha_i|^2 $.